# Replace non-ASCII characters in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, regular-expression

I want to replace all non-standard characters from fields in a dbf table in QGIS.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space

I see we can use something like

```
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','_',  "New_Name" )
```

But I am not sure how to use this in the the Expression or Function Editor module.

So I have a column called "New_Name" which I want the !@#$%^&*()~`+ etc signs removed and replaced with _

Can RE be used or do we need to specify each value to replace using CASE WHEN or Replace -the solution in RE is better if it can be done in QGIS Field Calculator using the regexp_replace expression?

Comment: have you tried using **regexp_replace("field",'\W','_')**, might be simpler? (not tried it but worth a go)

Comment: Didn't know you could - I get "An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: Invalid regular expression '?': bad repetition syntax" this is using [regexp_replace( "New_Name" ,'\W','_')] @StevenKay

Comment: It looks as if  \W might not be supported in regexp_replace(), but it should work in Python's re.sub() ( And I should have used \W+ )

Comment: @StevenKay - You're close! You just need a double backslash for `\\W` so the expression should read `regexp_replace( "field", '\\W+', '_' )`. Consider posting it as an answer :)

Comment: @Joseph thanks. That worked perfectly. Steven why don't you add it in as an answer as mentioned by Joseph :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **`\W`** (upper case W) to match any non-alphanumeric characters.

If using **regexp_replace()** it seems you need to escape the backslash, so it becomes **`\\W`** (thanks, Joseph!)

For example

```
regexp_replace( '=+&hello%%£world','\\W+','_')
```

returns

```
_hello_world
```

If using the python equivalent function **re.sub()**, you probably won't need to escape the backslash.